# Why isn't my programming working when I enter the number: 600851475143

Tags: java, prime-factoring

I'm currently doing [problem 3](https://projecteuler.net/problem=3) from Project Euler. This the problem I need to solve:
What is the largest prime factor of the number 600851475143 ?
My code compiles as expected when I enter smaller numbers such as 10,000. But when I enter the number from the problem: 600851475143, nothing happens. 
Here is my code:

```
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    class problem3{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        ArrayList<Long> rr = findFactors(600851475143L);// rr holds an Array of factors. 
        rr = largestPrime(rr); // rr now holds an Array of factors that are prime.
        int sizeOfrr = rr.size();
        long largestPrimeFactor = rr.get(sizeOfrr-1);// prints the last(largest) prime factor
        System.out.println(largestPrimeFactor);
        /*This loops through all of the prime factors found
        for(int i = 0; i<rr.size(); i++){
            System.out.println(rr.get(i));
        }*/
        System.exit(0);

    }
    // This method returns an array of factors of the Long argument passed into parameter number.
    public static ArrayList<Long> findFactors(Long number){
        ArrayList<Long> factors = new ArrayList<Long>();
        for(Long i= 1L; i<=number; i++){ // Divide number by every single digit upto and including itself
            // Remember, we need to place L or l after an integer to let the compiler know its a long - not an int primitve.
            if(number%i == 0){ // If number modules i is equal to zero, then i is a factor.
                factors.add(i); // Append i to the factors array.
            }
        }
        return factors;
    }
    // Increments the unit divisor, starting at 2L
    /* The goal is to find if primeArray[i] has more than one factor. (Exluding 1 itself)
    The loop begins at 2L. If primeArray[i]%j == 0, counter will increment by one.
    The moment counter hits 2, we know primeArray[i] is not a prime since if it were prime,
    the counter would be set to 1 and only 1 (because counter would only increment when j is
    equal to primeArray[i] or in otherwords, when it is equal to itself. )
    The method below returns an array of all the prime numbers
    */
    public static ArrayList<Long> largestPrime(ArrayList<Long> primeArray){
        int counter =0;
        for(int i = 0; i<primeArray.size(); i++){ // Loops through the prime array
            for(Long j = 2L; j<= primeArray.get(i); j++){
                // (iL)??; jL++) { // 2L/3 for instance
                    if(primeArray.get(i)%j == 0){// Is it a factor?
                        counter++;
                    }
                    if(counter > 1){
                        primeArray.remove(i);
                        counter = 0;
                        break;
                    }
                    if(j == primeArray.get(i)){
                        counter = 0;
                    }
            }
        }
        return primeArray;
    }
}
```

Comment: The most important thing you can learn from this problem is how to use a debugger. Using a debugger not only help finds bugs, it emboldens you to try experiments which in turn help you become an expert.

Comment: The program is probably still running, because you're looping 600851475143 times. As far as I know, Project Euler problems require you to think outside the box instead of writing straight-forward programs that brute-force their way to the solution.

Answer (score -1):

> nothing happens

As Qbrute said, you're looping 600851475143 times. It takes really a lot.

Since you have to find the largest prime factor, you don't need to find every factor, so you could skip every even number.
You could find first every prime factor and few others, then keep only the prime ones just comparing the ones you found each other.
Moreover the first loop can end at `Math.sqrt(input)`. What about the (prime) factors above that? Just do input/factor.
Lastly you can keep your array sorted, this way you can stop looking for a prime after the first one. You should also use the primitive every time you can.

These optimization should be enough.
Try this:

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {
    final long n = 600851475143L;
    final long largestPrime = findLargestPrimeFactors(n);
    System.out.println("The largest prime of " + n + " is: " + largestPrime);
}

public static long findLargestPrimeFactors(final long num) {
    final List<Long> factors = new ArrayList<>();

    int index = 0;
    if ((num % 2L) == 0) {
        factors.add(num / 2L);
        factors.add(2L);
        index = 1;
    }

    final long end = Double.valueOf(Math.floor(Math.sqrt(num))).longValue();

    for (long i = 3L; i <= end; i += 2) { // skip every even number
        if ((num % i) == 0) {
            // This way the list is sorted in descending order
            factors.add(index++, (num / i));
            factors.add(index, i);
        }
    }

    final long largestPrime = retainsLargestPrime(factors);

    return largestPrime != 1L ? largestPrime : num; // if largestPrime is 1 it means that num is a prime number
}

private static long retainsLargestPrime(final List<Long> factors) {
    long largestPrime = 1L;

    if ((factors != null) && !factors.isEmpty()) {
        final int size = factors.size();
        for (int i = 0; (i < size) && (largestPrime == 1L); i++) {
            boolean isPrime = true;
            final long l = factors.get(i);
            for (int j = i + 1; (j < size) && isPrime; j++) {
                isPrime = !((l % factors.get(j)) == 0); // stop the inner loop as soon as possible
            }
            if (isPrime) {
                largestPrime = l;
            }
        }
    }
    return largestPrime;
}
```